# Which index to use in order to access items in defaultdict

Tags: python

I am using var_dict = defaultdict(list).
Then the key is 'NODE' and value is a list.
I am able to iterate thru the values. But if I want to access elements `['1974'], ['993'],['198']...` in this example can you please tell me what what would be the for loop construction for this.

```
var_dict['NODE']
[[['1013'], ['1974'], ['0/5']], [['1013'], ['993'], ['0/9']], [['9999'], ['198'], ['0/5']], [['9999'], ['992'], ['0/9']]]
```

I am able to iterate thru dictionary values given a key. My question is, what if I want to access items

```
for item in node_PS_if_list['IF_PSE2']:
    for item1 in item:
```

will list the respective value. What I need is to access the second element like `zz[0][1], zz[1][1], ZZ[2][1]` etc.

I would need to increment a variable i and pass it like [i][0], [1][1], [2][1] etc. I would appreciate your assistance to address syntax for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var_dict = {'NODE':[[['1013'], ['1974'], ['0/5']], [['1013'], ['993'], ['0/9']], [['9999'], ['198'], ['0/5']], [['9999'], ['992'], ['0/9']]]}

r = [x[1] for x in var_dict['NODE']]
print(r)
```

Result:

```
[['1974'], ['993'], ['198'], ['992']]
```

If you want to iterate over these:

```
for element in [x[1] for x in var_dict['NODE']]:
    # do your thing here
```

Comment: Just a suggestion: to save on memory, you could use a generator expression for iterating.

Comment: Yes, of course. With large data sets, that would definitely be worth doing.